# Change cell when INDIRECT formula is dragged down

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have the following formula set-up: `=INDIRECT("'Passed to Salesforce (digital only)'!A46",TRUE)`

However I'd like the A46 number to update when I drag the formula down.

I've tried using the `&CELL` but can't get it to quite work:

```
=INDIRECT("'Passed to Salesforce (digital only)'!A46""!"&CELL("address",TRUE))
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you're trying to do in your second formula.

The first one won't change the reference because it is just text not an actual cell reference. If you only want to update the row, not the column you could use `ROW()` to get the current cell's row add an offset (e.g. if you start with your formula in row 1 and want A46 your offset is 45):

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW()+45,TRUE)
```

Comment: Not sure I explained this very well:

I have the following table:

First Name | Last Name
Bob            | Smith

I am using =INDIRECT on a second sheet so that when I insert a new row at the bottom of the first sheet the formula pulls in the data without jumping a row.

The problem is since I am using =INDIRECT when I drag the formula down the cell references remain the same, I'd like these to update otherwise I'm stuck changing them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, I had to remove the first cell reference and duplicate exclamation mark:

```
=INDIRECT("'Passed to Salesforce (digital only)'!"&CELL("address", A47))
```